# Tab layout not displaying as I want

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am using custom background for my Tab layout, but it displaying something different. As 
[image]

but I want as

[image]

and my code is as

```
for(int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0079AD"));
            ((TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8CD7F2"));
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009ED6"));
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting effect as I wan't I am using drawable image as follow and I am getting result as I wan't almost same as your.

```
ImageView view1;
TabHost tabHost;
tabHost = getTabHost()
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

view1 = new ImageView(this);
view1.setOnTouchListener(view1Touch);//for identifying touch newly added.
view1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_image);
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AnohterActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_1).setIndicator(view1).setContent(
                intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

=======================

```
OnTouchListener view1Touch = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_focus);
        }
```

}

and TabChangeListener you might be already added.

Comment: but if I use this how can I implement selectors? please guide me.